# RDLC report for multiple checked box items in Listview in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, listview, rdlc

I need a little help here.

I have a form which shows all the clients, stored in the access database, as a check-box items in a listview control. I want a user to check multiple checkboxes to view details of the selected clients and show it in the rdlc report.

I have written the following codes in VB.net at form_load event, but it only shows the last selected item.

I want some seggustion for the codes which shows details in the rdlc report for all the selected clients.

```
Private Sub TodaysPendingCompliances_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    For Each SelctedCLient As ListViewItem In TodaysCompliances.ListView1.CheckedItems
        Me.NoticeComplianceTableAdapter.FillByClientANDComplianceDate(Me.ComplianceDBDataSet.NoticeCompliance, SelctedCLient.Text)
    Next

    Me.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
End Sub
```

You help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Mr. Bradlet Uffner for you response. You reply helped in finding the solution.

The solution is to set the Clearbeforefill = False for the `NoticeComplianceTableAdater`

Setting Clearbeforefill to false does not clear the existing data with fresh data from the current iteration.

Answer (score 0):

I beleive your problem is that `NoticeComplianceTableAdapter.FillByClientANDComplianceDate` overwrites the existing data with fresh data from the current iteration every time it is called, so it only holds the last iteration data.

To fix that you will either need to modify that function (or create an overload for it) to not clear the existing data, or create a temporary container that you declare before the loop, and add new data to each time, then attach the report to that temporary data.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you suggest me some code which will be easy for me understand the problem.